# Java Generics - Abstract Classes abstract function override

Tags: java, android, generics, abstract-class

I am trying to implement base abstract class in android.

My base abstract class is BaseItemPresenter class. Class is below :

```
public abstract class BaseItemPresenter<T extends MvpView> extends BasePresenter<T> {

    public abstract void loadFromDevice();

    public abstract void loadFromFile();

    public abstract void backup(List<? extends BaseBackupItem> list);

    public abstract void delete(List<? extends BaseBackupItem> list);

    public abstract void restore(List<? extends BaseBackupItem> list);

    public abstract void sort(int sortType, boolean isAscending);

    public abstract void sort(List<? extends BaseBackupItem> list, int sortType, boolean isAscending);

    public abstract void filter(List<? extends BaseBackupItem> list, Class<? extends MvpView> filterOptions);
}
```

and I am implementing this class with ItemPresenter1 class. Code is below :

```
public class ItemPresenter1 extends BaseItemPresenter<MvpView> {

    @Override
    public void loadFromDevice() {

    }

    @Override
    public void loadFromFile() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backup(List<Item1> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(List<Item1> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void restore(List<Item1> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sort(int sortType, boolean isAscending) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sort(List<Item1> list, int sortType, boolean isAscending) {

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(List<Item1> list, Class<View1> filterOptions) {

    }
}
```

Item1 class is extending BaseBackupItem class.
View1 class is extending MvpView class.

```
public class Item1 extends BaseBackupItem {

}

public class View1 extends MvpView {

}
```

so, how should I achieve this problem :

from :

```
public abstract void backup(List<? extends BaseBackupItem>);
```

to :

```
@Override
public void backup(List<Item1>);
```

error :

```
Method does not override method from its superclass.
```

Comment: Add another generic parameter to the class, and use IT as the list's type

Comment: why do you need to change the signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a **new type parameter** to the class definition of `BaseItemPresenter` in order to specify the expected type of your `List` as next:

```
public abstract class BaseItemPresenter<T extends MvpView, I extends BaseBackupItem> 
    extends BasePresenter<T> {
    ...
    public abstract void backup(List<I> list);

    public abstract void delete(List<I> list);

    public abstract void restore(List<I> list);

    ...
}
```

Then your class `ItemPresenter1` will be declared as next:

```
public class ItemPresenter1 extends BaseItemPresenter<MvpView, Item1 > {
    ...
    @Override
    public void backup(List<Item1> list) {
```